# .htaccess RewriteRule trying to make a link simpler problems

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make a link simpler.

For example:

From

```
example.com/r.php?i=1
```

To

```
example.com/1
```

What I tried to do is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ r.php?i= [L,QSA]
```

But it does not work unless I do:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ r.php?i=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And I want it to be done automatically, based on what the user puts in in the link.

I also tried:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ r.php?i=%{REQUEST_URL} [L,QSA]
```

And

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ r.php?i={REQUEST_URL} [L,QSA]
```

None of them seem to work.
I have no experience in `.htaccess` files.

Comment: try this 

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/1/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Your example should work just fine, note that the `$1` has nothing to do with the number `1`, it is simply the first captured variable which is your case is everthing.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ r.php?i=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: How is this different from what the OP has?

Comment: It's fine. I did it again and it seems to work. It's probably just something I didn't notice before.